# Loosing file format after downloading a file and uploading to some other cloud

Tags: google-drive-api

I am downloading a file stream from Drive and uploading to some other Cloud. For Excel/Docs files loosing the formatting of the file.

API Used to download stream : https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId.

Is There any way to preserve the formatting.

[Please Check Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwyeh.png)

Comment: please edit your question include your code and describe any issues you have with your code.   You should consider using google dive v3

Comment: As @DaImTo said it'd be helpful for the community to better understand your question.